# Normed linear space and scalar field

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, real-numbers

I am confused for the normed linear spaces and scalar field. Let $X$ be a normed linear space equipped with norm $||\cdot||$ over the scalar field $F$.

If $\exists x\not= 0$ in $X$ then is it possible (to prove or disprove using only the definition of the norm) that $\dfrac{x}{||x||+1}$ is also in it? I only know that $\alpha x\in X$ if $\alpha\in F$ but what if $F\not =\mathbb R,\mathbb C$ and the norm is defined to be $||\cdot||: X\rightarrow [0,\infty)$, so how to understand this as the field maybe finite field or something that is not compatible with $[0,\infty)$. I am really confused on this.

Comment: A normed space is always a vector space over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C,$ or at least over some field equipped with an absolute value map.

Comment: Since $\lVert x \rVert + 1$ and its reciprocal are real numbers, this only makes sense if $F$ has $\mathbb{R}$ as a subfield. It usually poses some technical problems since you cannot for instance divide a vector by its norm to obtain a unit vector.